# finding string that starts or ends with greek letters in python

Tags: python

I want to find a string that starts or ends with greek letters. I wrote a python script for it but did not give the desired result.

```
greekletters = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "zata", "eta", "theta", "iota","kappa", "lambda", "mu", "nu", "xi", "omikron", "pi", "rho", "sigma", "tau", "upsilon", "phi","chi", "psi", "omega"]
gl=["-alpha", "-beta", "-gamma", "-delta", "-epsilon", "-zata", "-eta", "-theta", "-iota" "- kappa", "-lambda", "-mu", "-nu", "-xi", "-omikron", "-pi", "-rho", "-sigma", "-tau","-upsilon", "-phi", "-chi", "-psi", "-omega"]
file="C:/Python26/test.txt"
f=open("greekletters.txt",'w')
with open(file,'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines();
    c=0
    for word in lines:
        if word.strip() in greekletters or word.startswith(tuple(greekletters)) or word.endswith(tuple(gl)):
##            f.write('1'"\n")
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'1'"\n")
            c=c+1
        else:
##            f.write('0'"\n")
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'0'"\n")
            c=c+1
    print c
    f.close()
```

Comment: NOTE:My txt file contains each token on a single line, i paste it from my file but it don't appear in that way

test.txt is 

123[worker]
[IL-2]
{shaheen123}
wo(rker)
(123.321)
{
[
}
]
(
)
a[s{d(dsa)}]
an
sde
all
ATCGGAS
shhII
alpha
beta
gamma
googa-alpha
betasystol
beta-systol
googa-beta
googabeta

Comment: and result is

123[worker] 0
[IL-2] 0
{shaheen123} 0
wo(rker) 0
(123.321) 0
{ 0
[ 0
} 0
] 0
( 0
) 0
a[s{d(dsa)}] 0
an 0
sde 0
all 0
ATCGGAS 0
shhII 0
alpha 1
beta 1
gamma 1
googa-alpha 0
betasystol 1
beta-systol 1
googa-beta 0
googabeta 0


it show the googa-beta, googa-alpha and googabeta "0" while it must show it as "1"

Comment: I tink endswith() not working properly

Comment: You say it didn't result in what you expected, but you don't say what it did do.  Can you add that?  Also, can you give us an idea of what the input actually looks like?

Comment: Can you edit your comments into your question, and while you are at it, also fix the title? That would make the whole thing much more readable and will yield better answers.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a file you need to trim the new line character (`'\n'`) from the line with `rstrip`, additionally, if you want to ignore start and end whitespaces, you can directly use `strip`:

```
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    tgreek = tuple(greekletters)
    if line in greekletters or line.startswith(tgreek) or line.endswith(tgreek):
        do something
```

should work. If you don't remove the line break `'\n'` from the end of the line in advance, the sentence will never `endswith` a greek letter. The same happens if the sentence has blank spaces at the begining or end.

Replace by `line = line.rstrip('\n')` if you don't want to ignore blank spaces.

Additionally, if you open a file using `with`, you don't need to `close` it, at the end of the `with` statement python automatically does for you.